# click thumbnail and load image into empty div

Tags: jquery, load, thumbnails

Loading images from thumbnails seems to have been covered ad nauseum but I just can't wrap my brain around it. Here's my html where #sideWall holds the thumbs and I want the hi-rez to go into #photoHolder...

```
<div id="graphicContainer">
<div id="sideWall">
    <span class="sideHead">EXHIBITS</span><br/>
    <span class="sideChatter">Click an image to learn more.</span><br/>
    <img src="images/frisco4501_t.jpg" full="frisco4501.jpg" />
    <img src="images/centennial_t.jpg" full="centennial.jpg" />
    <!--     etc...     -->
</div> <!--End of sidewall-->
<div id="photoHolder"></div>
```

Here's my $. The alert() is returning the right directory and the fade is working, the image just isn't loading...

```
$('#sideWall img').each(function(){
    $this = $(this);
    $image = "../images/"+$this.attr('full');
    $this.click(function(){
        alert($image);
        $("#photoHolder").html('<img src="'+$image +'" />');
        $("#photoHolder").fadeIn(2000);         
    })
});
```

Comment: why are you getting attribute 'full' and not the 'src'?

Comment: full image not in same  directory?

Comment: @immanish 'src' is a separate image with a "_t" at the end. The full rez version has no "_t." Both are in the same directory.

Comment: @immanish 'index.html' is in a directory with 'includes' and 'images' the thumbs and the hi-rez live in the 'images' directory.

Comment: remove '../' from $image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, the solution can be done more simply:

```
$('#sideWall img').click(function(){
  var c = $(this).attr("src").replace('_t.','.');
  $("#photoHolder").html('<img src="'+ c +'" />');
  $("#photoHolder").fadeIn(2000);         
})
```

sure in case (of common praxis) - thumb has same name and is in same directory. No attribute 'full' is needed then.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed it. After looking at this, I'm still not sure where my original code is broken?

Comment: if your alert was showing directory, then only '$this.attr('full')' left to be in trouble.

Comment: is it possible to cache the downloeaded images?

Comment: Cache is managed by browser. If you want preload full size images then  let them load on to the end of page to hidden container. They will be taken from browser cache on zoom.

Answer (score 1):

No need for the `.each()`. jQuery handles collections out of the box.
Also, use HTML5 `data-*` attribute to store the larger image src string:

```js
$('#sideWall').on('click', '[data-src2x]', function() {
  const src2x = $(this).data('src2x');
  $("#photoHolder").hide().html(`<img src="${src2x}">`).fadeIn();         
});
```

```html
<div id="graphicContainer">

  <div id="sideWall">
      <h4 class="sideHead">EXHIBITS</h4>
      <p class="sideChatter">Click an image to learn more.</p>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x50/cf5" data-src2x="http://placehold.it/200x100/cf5" />
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x50/f0f" data-src2x="http://placehold.it/200x100/f0f" />
  </div>
  
  <div id="photoHolder"></div>
  
</div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
$('#sideWall img').click(function(){
    $image = "../images/"+$(this).attr('data-full');
    alert($image);
    $("#photoHolder").html('<img src="'+$image +'" />').fadeIn(2000);         
});
```

Didn't have to test it but it should work.
Note that I changed the attr 'full' to 'data-full' to make it HTML5 valid.